# Error with react-native JSX elements when using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am creating an app using react-native and typescript.

I am facing following errors;

```
<AuthDetails
            style={{ marginTop: 60 }} // this line is giving error1.
            setUdaisId={this.setUdaisId}
            setPassword={this.setPassword}
          />
```

**error1**: [ts] Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>...'.

Similarly,

```
<TextInput
  underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
  secureTextEntry={true}
  placeholder = "Password"
  placeHolderStyle = {styles.placeHolderStyle} // this line is giving error2.
  style = {[styles.textInput, {marginTop:20}]}
/>
```

**error2** : [ts] Property 'placeHolderStyle' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & ...'.

And

```
  <Image
    style={styles.avatar}
    source={this.state.avatarSource}
    resizeMode={this.state.resizeMode} //this line gives error3.
/>
```

**error3** : [ts]
Type '{ style: RegisteredStyle; source: any; resizeMode: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & Read...'.
  Type '{ style: RegisteredStyle; source: any; resizeMode: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.
    Types of property 'resizeMode' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"center" | "stretch" | "cover" | "contain" | "repeat" | undefined'.

Comment: What does your ```AuthDetails``` class line look like?